# One write-thread, one read-thread on the same socket?

Tags: multithreading, sockets

i am running eCos with the FreeBSD TCP/IP-stack. Is it safe to have two threads running one to read from a socket and one to write to the same socket?

Well i guess since its the FreeBSD stack the operating system does not matter.

Best regards,

Friedrich

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, sockets are full duplex, meaning we can read from and write to the same socket at the same time.  However, you have to make sure that there's only 1 reader and 1 writer at a time.
  Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong.  One thread can be reading while another thread is writing at the same time.  If multiple threads read, or multiple threads write, you have to manually serialize access to that side of the socket to prevent overlaps.

Comment: I have a question...suppose that bytes are written in the same syscall `write`. Is possible overlapping of writers in a kernel compiled without kernel preemption on a machine with a single CPU?

Comment: @MirkoBanchi I'm not pretty sure what your question is, but yes, writers can overlap themselves if they are not handled properly.  Imagine you want to send out 2 big files, in 2 separate threads, over a socket where you have to loop through write()/send() until it finishes.

Comment: @shinkou i supposed that _all_ bytes are written in the same syscall so, without kernel preemption (on a not SMP machine), a context switch in kernel space is not possible so there won't be overlapping. In your context yes, overlapping is possible. Thank you for your comment.